# Writing Python script to simulate two electrons - electrons moving in parallel directions instead of collinearly

Tags: python, math

I am trying to write a Python program to simulate two electrons interacting with one another, with only the Couloumb force acting upon them. So, they should be moving in paths that are collinear with one another, but for some reason, my simulated electrons are moving in paths that are parallel to one another.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Sep 20 10:01:24 2023

@author: sanat 
"""

import pygame
import sys
import math

# Constants
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 2000, 1000
BACKGROUND_COLOR = (255, 255, 255)
ELECTRON_RADIUS = 5
TIME_STEP = 0.01  # Time step for simulation

# Electron properties
electron1 = {
    "pos": [400, 500],
    "velocity": [0, 0],
    "charge": - 1.0,
    "mass": 1.0
}

electron2 = {
    "pos": [900, 600],
    "velocity": [0, 0],
    "charge": -1.0,
    "mass": 1.0
}

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Electron Motion Simulation")

def calculate_force(e1, e2):
    k = 8.988e9  # Coulomb's constant
    r = math.sqrt((e1["pos"][0] - e2["pos"][0]) ** 2 + (e1["pos"][1] - e2["pos"][1]) ** 2)
    force = (k * e1["charge"] * e2["charge"]) / (r ** 2)
    return force

def update_velocity(electron, force):
    acceleration = force / electron["mass"]
    electron["velocity"][0] += acceleration * TIME_STEP
    electron["velocity"][1] += acceleration * TIME_STEP

def update_position(electron):
    electron["pos"][0] += electron["velocity"][0] * TIME_STEP
    electron["pos"][1] += electron["velocity"][1] * TIME_STEP

def draw_electrons():
    for electron in [electron1, electron2]:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), (int(electron["pos"][0]), int(electron["pos"][1])), ELECTRON_RADIUS)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Calculate force between electrons
    force = calculate_force(electron1, electron2)

    # Update velocities and positions
    update_velocity(electron1, force)
    update_velocity(electron2, -force)  # Opposite force on electron2
    update_position(electron1)
    update_position(electron2)

    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)

    # Draw electrons
    draw_electrons()

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(1000)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

So, that is the code that I have, and I am not quite sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Think carefully about the logic of the code. When you `calculate_force` caused by the Coulomb force, *what direction* should that be applied in? *How do you know*? If you look at the result from that function, *does it tell you* the direction somehow? Therefore, when you apply the Euler integration logic, *how could it know* the direction of the force (and thus accelerate in the correct direction*? You apparently understand that position and velocity are supposed to be vector quantities rather than scalars, but seem to have overlooked that this also applies to force and acceleration.

Comment: (If there is any actual *question* here rather than a simple logical oversight, it would appear to be a question about math or physics rather than programming.) More bluntly: if 1N of force is applied to a 1kg object, it should accelerate at 1m/s^2, yes? Okay, *which direction* does it move?

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I don't know how I missed that. Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes to point out a silly mistake haha

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Karl, I was able to fix the code. I was missing a way to find the direction of the force vectors, and was able to resolve like so:

```
def calculate_force_vector(e1, e2):
    k = 8.988e9  # Coulomb's constant
    r_vector = np.array(e1["pos"]) - np.array(e2["pos"])
    r_magnitude = np.linalg.norm(r_vector)
    force_magnitude = (k * e1["charge"] * e2["charge"]) / (r_magnitude ** 2)
    force_direction = r_vector / r_magnitude  # Normalize the direction vector
    force_vector = force_magnitude * force_direction
    return force_vector
```